# Python: Calling module's functions from within a class

Tags: python, module

I have the following code:

```
from suchandsuch import bot

class LaLaLa():
    def __init__(self):
        self.donenow = 0
        print "LaLaLa() initialized."
        return

    def start(self):
        pages = bot.cats_recursive('something')
        for page in pages:
            self.process_page(page)
```

When I try to run `y = LaLaLa()` and then `y.start()`, though, I get an error:

```
AttributeError: LaLaLa instance has no attribute 'cats_recursive'
```

This makes me suspect that Python is trying to call cats_recursive() *not* from suchandsuch's bot sub-module (as is defined at the beginning of the file), but rather from LaLaLa(), which of course doesn't have the cats_recursive() function. Is there a way to force a class instance to use an imported module, rather than just look inside itself?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with this code. Your real code probably does something different... Can you post it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posters are correct that there is nothing wrong with the code you have posted.

It's the code you **didn't** post that is probably the problem.  It is hinted at in your naming of cats_recursive.  You haven't shown us that perhaps LaLaLa is defined in or imported into bot.py.

One way to replicate your error is:

```
# in suchandsuch/bot.py

class LaLaLa():
    def __init__(self):
        self.donenow = 0
        print "LaLaLa() initialized."
        #  don't need a `return` here

def start(self):
    pages = bot.cats_recursive('something')
    for page in pages:
        self.process_page(page)

bot = LaLaLa()
```

That's just one.  Another is to have `__init__.py` in such and such something like:

```
bot = LaLaLa()
```

Like I said, the error is in your code structure.

print the id of the bot inside LaLaLa or captrue the error with pydb and I suspect you will see that bot is an instance of LaLaLa other than y (again check the id's)

Comment: The error was that I had set the instance of LaLaLa() to a variable named bot - exactly as you exemplified! Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing fine. *Most probably there is no `cats_recursive()` attribute in your module for real.* Check syntax, check module content.

Comment: Well, the message does refer to a `LaLaLa` instance. That would mean there's another class named `LaLaLa` (defined or used) in `suchandsuch`.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the easiest way to do this would be to try to assign the `cats_recursive()` to the `pages` variable outside the class and then pass the variable to the `start()` function as a parameter. If this works then keep it that way, if it doesn't work then there's probably something wrong with the code elsewhere.